# Can I enable DEX verbose logging?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I moved my Android IntelliJ IDEA project from one location to another. For some reason, IDEA lost all the modules and I had to re-import them.

Now when I compile, I get this DEX error:

```
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] Unable to execute DX 
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/common/base/FinalizableReference; 
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594) 
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552) 
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533) 
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170) 
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188) 
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439) 
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)     
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230) 
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:161)      
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:294) 
Error:Android Dex: [MyApp] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)
```

I can't figure out what the cause is, all the usual suspects of multiple JARs seems to be ok.

Is there a way to turn on verbose logging to get a better understanding on which libs are in conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to get better error description from DEX, but here are 2 suggestions to troubleshoot:

1. If using Android Studio, just search for the offending class `FinalizableReference` (include non-project classes in the search).
   (Use `Command+N` for find class or double tap `Shift` for "search everywhere".
   For eclipse: `Ctrl+Shift+T`? others can confirm.
2. Using the command line: `jar tf mylib.jar | grep FinalizableReference` will search mylib for the class. You can then use some shell `for` loop over the jar files (usually in libs dir).
   Also `grep -r FinalizableReference libs/*\.jar` will scan all the jars (assuming you have them in libs) and notify the ones that have a match (the duplicates).